# Is there a way to classify industry category through occupation name?

Tags: python, classification, prediction, categorization

I'm trying to retrieve the industry from occupation values. There are around 50 distinctive values, some of them are straightforward for example: 'Financial services professional','Consultant', 'Lawyer'; some are very non specific like 'Member of management', 'Entrepreneur' or 'Independent Gentleman'...

Is there a way for me to sort the readable data into categories like 'Law', 'Financial Services' and all the rest into 'Other'?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 50 distinctive values, the most straightforward way is for you to create the categories manually.

If you are doing this as a project to improve your data science and programming skills you can read on how to do text classification with BERT or other transformer models

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's exactly what I'm looking for. Will check on BERT.